# Usage and meaning of the word "Rather"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> "It's rather cold outside"

I've recently heard this expression in a movie, but I didn't get the meaning of it. I've searched it on the Internet and found that different sites explained its meaning in different ways. I am a little bit confused what the speaker is trying to say using the word **"rather"**

It could be

> "it is a little bit cold outside"

or

> "it is too cold outside"

I think that it mainly depends on the situation when the speaker uses this word. Therefore, I would like to ask what are most common ways of using the word "**rather**".

Comment: I think the last edit took the point out of the question. The original question included '(...)I  searched it on the Internet (...) I found that some sites are saying that rather means "quite, a little bit or to some extent" but some sites are saying that it means "to a notable extent, greatly".' This is gone now and the recent answer doesn't address this part of the question... @Varun did you consider that?

Comment: Have a look at Dce  http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rather

Answer (score 1):

This is a very commonly used word to express emphasis on the subject of conversation.

> It is **rather** cold outside.

This simply means that it is *'fairly'* cold outside.

This means that to a certain degree or extent, as per the speaker, it is cold outside. It neither means it is *"a little bit"* or *"too"* cold outside. From the speaker's perspective, it is cold. To what extent? That depends on the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

'Rather' means ***less than very***. it's considered a synonym of 'quite' or 'fairly', but we often use it when something is a **surprise**.

> Her cooking is rather good actually. (= better than I thought and a very nice surprise)

In your example, the speaker means

*it's quite cold outside and it's a surprise (maybe he thought it would be warmer)* or *it's quite cold and the speaker doesn't like the situation i.e. he doesn't like it to be cold*

so he says,

> It's rather cold outside.

Let me put a continuum of adverbs of intensity here that I learnt somewhere. Not all adverbs are included though. Hope it can be useful. It gets stronger moving from 1 to 3.

1. a bit/slightly -> *less than quite*
2. quite/fairly/rather/pretty -> *less than very*
3. very/extremely/incredibly/really